# Templatefield in gridview

Tags: gridview, asp-classic, linkbutton, templatefield

how can i get the values stored in one column of the gridview? this is the code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Document Code" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#000099" HeaderStyle-Width="150px">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="doc_code" Text='<%# Eval("doc_code")%>' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("doc_id") %>'
                            OnCommand="editDocument" CausesValidation="false">
                            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span>          
                        </asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

i always get a blank value from this column i dont know how to get its values. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Bind` in place of `Eval` as shown in below solution.

```
 <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="doc_code" Text='<%# Bind("doc_code")%>' CommandArgument='<%# Bind("doc_id") %>' OnCommand="editDocument" CausesValidation="false">
```